GTM Server-side tagging 'tcp-rst-from-server' issue
We have setup a GTM Server container using Automatically provision tagging server (Google Cloud) and also configured out GTM Web container accordingly. When running tests in preview mode the Web Container is showing hits sent but the Server container is not capturing any data. Checking with our IT dept the firewall logs are showing the 'Session End Reason' is tcp-rst-from-server. Have we missed something in the standard documentation setup causing this?
We have setup another GTM server container but using Taggrs rather than Google Cloud and this shows data captured, again following the same standard documentation.
Against the Google cloud server we have run the /healthy test against the default url and this worked, we have also created test query parameters appended to the default url and fired these from another browser window. Again these worked, it is only when running the web and server containers in preview mode that we can not appearing to collect the data within the Google cloud server.
